анимация в консоли С++
как сделать анимацию в консоли на С++?
есть вариант каждый раз очищать консоль, но это долго.
какие есть хорошие альтернативы?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Как избавиться от мерцания при выводе в консоль?
